# Выход изображения за край экрана при анимации

Tags: html, css

На сайте имеется блок с изображением на весь экран (просто штука для антуража и красоты), на первом снимке - изображение с экрана 1366х768, а на втором - 1920х1080. При анимации на экране меньшего разрешения, объекты выходят за край. Как это можно исправить? Код ниже.

```css
*{
   font-family: Stolzl;
}

body {
    background-image: url("background.png");
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
  }

#vz{
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 10px;
  font-family: Comfortaa;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-left: 20px;
}
#vz:hover{
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 10px;
  font-family: Comfortaa;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-left: 20px;
  animation-name: slide;
  animation-duration: 0.5s;
}
.menuButton{
  position: absolute;
  top: 30px;
  left: 300px;
  font-family: Stolzl;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #6E6E6E;
}
#homeButton{
  margin-left: 100px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
#homeButton:hover{
  animation-name: slide;
  animation-duration: 0.5s;
  margin-left: 100px;
  color: #0000FF;
  text-decoration: none;
}
#secondButton{
  margin-left: 230px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
#secondButton:hover{
  animation-name: slide;
  animation-duration: 0.5s;
  margin-left: 230px;
  color: #0000FF;
  text-decoration: none;
}
#x{
  background-image: url('x.png');
  width: 1531px;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: 871px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  top:90px;
  animation-name: right;
  animation-duration: 10s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}
#dev{
  color: white;
}
#logoImg{
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  background-image: url("logo.png");
  width: 133px;
  height: 45px;
  background-size: cover;
  margin-left: 30px;
  margin-top: 5px;
}
#header{
  height: 50px;
  border: 2px solid #FFFFFF;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border-radius: 15px;
  padding: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 7px 0px black;
}
#welcomeT{
  margin-top: 70px;
  font-size: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: lighter;
  animation-name: levitate;
  animation-duration: 4s;
  animation-delay: 0.5s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}
#vzText{
  margin-top: 70px;
  font-size: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Comfortaa;
  font-weight: normal;
}
#square{
  position: absolute;
  left: 200px;
  top: 16px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-size: 100%;
  background-image: url('square.png');
  animation-name: rotation;
  animation-duration: 3s;
  animation-delay: 0.5s;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
}
#square:hover{
  position: absolute;
  left: 200px;
  top: 16px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-size: 100%;
  background-image: url('square.png');
  animation-name: rotation;
  animation-duration: 3s;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  animation-play-state: running;
}

@keyframes rotation  {

  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }

  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }

}

@keyframes slide {
  0%{
    transform: translateX(0px);
  }
  50%{
    transform: translateX(-20px);
  }
  100%{
    transform: translateX(0px);
  }
}

@keyframes levitate{
  0%{
    transform: translateY(0px);
  }

  50%{
    transform: translateY(-20px);
  }

  100%{
    transform: translateY(0px);
  }
}

@keyframes right{
  0%{
    transform: translateY(0px);
    transform: translateX(0px);
  }

  50%{
    transform: translateY(-10px);
    transform: translateX(190px);
  }

  100%{
    transform: translateY(0px);
    transform: translateX(0px);
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;
  charset=utf-8" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css" />
    <title>vedz | в разработке</title>

</head>
<body>
    <div id ="header">
    <a href="withcss.html"><div id ="logoImg"></div></a>
    <div id ="square"></div>
    <a id="homeButton" class="menuButton" href="withcss.html"> Главная </a>
    <a id="secondButton" class="menuButton"> Ещё страница </a>
  </div>

<div id="x"></div>
  <h1 id="welcomeT">Добро пожаловать на обновлённый сайт <span id ="vzText">vedz</span></h1>

</body>
</html>
```

[image: 1366х768[![][1]]

Comment: может быть `body {overflow-x:hidden;}` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуй так:

```
body { width: 100%; overflow-x: hidden; margin: 0}
```

Ну и header потом выровнять:

```
#header {margin: 0 8px}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое! Очень помогло. Долго искал ответ